# Levenshtein on dataframe column and input list

Tags: pyspark, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-comparison

New to pyspark and I need to do fuzzy match. Found that levenhenstein is a native function which can do that. I have a dataframe like this:

+----------------+----------------+
|             col1|       col2|
+----------------+----------------+
|            apple|        egg|
|            mango|      bread|
|           banana|      butter|

And an input list like ["apples","mango"]. I need to get all the (fuzzy) matches from col1 and input list.

I am using the following code:

```
input_array=["apples","mango"]
keyword_array=array([lit(x) for x in input_array])
keyword_string = array_join(keyword_array, "|")
result_df = df.filter(levenshtein("col1", keyword_string)<5)
```

levenshtein can only have parameters both as column or second one can be string. This code does not give any error, but it also does not give any result also(result_df.show() shows empty dataframe). Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong in this or the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting any row qualified for the `filter condition`.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('apple','egg'),('mango','bread'),('banana','butter')],['col1','col2'])
input_array=["apples","mango"]

keyword_array=array([lit(x) for x in input_array])
keyword_string = array_join(keyword_array, "|")
df.withColumn("keyword_tmp",keyword_string).\
withColumn('distance',levenshtein("col1", "tmp")).show(10,False)
#+------+------+------------+--------+
#|col1  |col2  |keyword_tmp |distance|
#+------+------+------------+--------+
#|apple |egg   |apples|mango|7       |
#|mango |bread |apples|mango|7       |
#|banana|butter|apples|mango|10      |
#+------+------+------------+--------+
```

As shown above the distance shows `7` but your filter condition has the distance of `<5`.

Change your filter condition to `result_df = df.filter(levenshtein("col1", keyword_string)<8)` to get your result.

Comment: levenshtein distance of 7 will give many false positives. I need to match input array with dataframe column. Is there any other way to do it. array_join seems to be only syntactically correct.